# Angular running on local adress uses https for files

Tags: angular

I am running my angular project on my local network with this command: `ng serve --host=<ip_adress>`. I can get onto the page via http from a mobile phone, but there I get the error message `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.
I don't have anything set with https, the base is set in the index.html like this
`<base href="/">`

[image]

Comment: Try using `--host=0.0.0.0` ?

Comment: didn't work, still tries to get via https

Comment: Have you try to run it with --host=<ip_adress> --ssl=false

Comment: yes tried that too, didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer/found my own mistake.

I still had the meta tag `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">` in my index.html head.